# Assigning random numbers in Excel to names that can be duplicated

Tags: excel

I have a long list of names in Excel, with some duplicated (which is valid). I need to assign a random unique identifier (preferably an integer between 1000 and 99999) to each unique name.

I've been trying to use the =RAND and =RANDBETWEEN functions, but if a name appears more than once, I need the same number to be assigned (e.g. John Snow should be assigned the same number each time the name appears).

Can this be done using VLOOKUP and RANDBETWEEN functions? Or by sorting names in order and using lag function in Excel?

Thank you very much. The purpose is to assign unique IDs to names for confidentiality purposes.

Comment: You can have one column which is just random numbers, and then a second column which checks if the name already exists and if so pulls the same generated number and if not points to the random number in the same row.  Something like `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A2)>0,VLOOKUP(A2,A:B,2,FALSE),B2)` (assumptions: column A is the names, column B is the random numbers, formula would go in cell C2 and be copied down).  And then you could just hide the random numbers column

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.